# Unable to create new build configuration on Visual Studio 2019 for VB.NET Web application

Tags: vb.net, build, visual-studio-2019, config, variant

I have an old VB.NET projet on Visual Studio 2019.
I am currently trying to create a new "Projet" configuration in order to have two builds variant : Release and Debug.

I managed to create a new build variant on the **Solution level** but in the "Configuration manager" menu, I can not create any other build configuration for my (only) project inside the solution.

I can only choose "Debug" and that's all.

I don't understand because I have on my folder all 3 files : Web.config, Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config that should be necessary to have a Release build.

[Build config Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTz3F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you need to have different data for debug and release, you can add compiler directives.

```
#If Not DEBUG Then
        path = Application.LocalUserAppDataPath
#Else
        path = IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
#End If
```

Comment: My issue is that I can not create a new build config for Release mode on project level.